# Java database query statement returns null

Tags: java, jdbc, javadb

I have a Java database set up in [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) 7, connected to it, but my query turns up null.

My database is named `Questioneer`, and the table is named `QNTABLE`, under the APP folder in the services tab.

I used the query

```
query = "select QNNAME from QNTABLE"; // (QNNAME is a field name) with the statement: 

Statement st = dbConn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

with this, but `st` and `rs` turned up as null.

Comment: According to the docs executeQuery() never returns null. Are you sure it's null and not an empty ResultSet?

Comment: Are you sure there is data in the QNTABLE ?

Comment: yes there is data in the table i've already accessed it using binding in a gui list.

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't compile, as Java uses " for string literals, not ''.

Your diagnostics are certainly off, as if `st` is null then the final line will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Basically, you should re-examine not just your code, but how you're approaching it. Work out whether you're *really* running the code you think you are, and how you're checking the values of variables.

If you have *instance* variables called `st` and `rs` and they're being hidden by *local* variables called `st` and `rs`, that could explain some of the confusion.

Comment: i'm typing on my phone, sorry about the wrong symbol. I'm also debugging the code, and from the variable watch window, i see null as the value of st and rs, they are local the the function in question, and that is where my error was, i was checking the value of the variable when the debuger got to the retunr statement, and by then the variables were sort of gone.

Comment: @TiOLUWA: "Sort of gone"? Put a break-point on the `createStatement` line, and watch the values as each line executes. As I stated - if `rs` were null, `st.executeQuery` would have failed. Perhaps later in the code something sets the values to null?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `query` variable. Maybe you're using double `'` instead of `"` or a single `'`.